# How can I programmatically update INKitRegister record without errors?

Tags: c#, acumatica

The following code successfully inserts an `INKitRegister` record.

```
public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    #region Event Handlers

    public virtual void _(Events.RowPersisting<SOLine> e)
    {            
        SOLine soLine = e.Row;

        InventoryItem inItem = PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Required<SOLine.inventoryID>>>>
            .Select(new PXGraph(), soLine.InventoryID);

        if (inItem == null)
            return;

        if (inItem.KitItem.HasValue && inItem.KitItem.Value)
        {
            SOLineExt soLineExt = soLine.GetExtension<SOLineExt>();
            INKitRegister kit = null;
            bool kitIsNew = false;

            if (soLineExt.INKitRegisterDocType != null && soLineExt.INKitRegisterRefNbr != null)
            {
                kit = PXSelect<INKitRegister, Where<INKitRegister.docType, Equal<Required<SOLineExt.iNKitRegisterDocType>>,
                                                And<INKitRegister.refNbr, Equal<Required<SOLineExt.iNKitRegisterRefNbr>>>>>
                .Select(new PXGraph(), soLineExt.INKitRegisterDocType, soLineExt.INKitRegisterRefNbr);
            }
            
            // If kit mix doesn't exist, create it
            if (kit == null)
            {
                kit = new INKitRegister();
                kitIsNew = true;
            }

            // Insert/update INKitRegister (new mix)
            var graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<KitAssemblyEntry>();
            graph.Document.Current = kit;
            graph.Document.Cache.SetValueExt<INKitRegister.tranDate>(kit, soLine.RequestDate);
            if (kitIsNew)
            {
                graph.Document.Cache.SetValueExt<INKitRegister.kitInventoryID>(kit, soLine.InventoryID);
            }                
            graph.Document.Cache.SetValueExt<INKitRegister.uOM>(kit, soLine.UOM);
            graph.Document.Cache.SetValueExt<INKitRegister.qty>(kit, soLine.Qty);
            //graph.Document.Cache.SetValueExt<INKitRegister.tranDesc>(kit, string.Format("{0} {1}", soLine.TranDesc));
            kit = graph.Document.Cache.Update(kit) as INKitRegister;
            graph.Actions.PressSave();
            
            // Save the mix props to the SOLine
            soLineExt.INKitRegisterDocType = kit.DocType;
            soLineExt.INKitRegisterRefNbr = kit.RefNbr;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

When I attempt to change the Qty on an SOOrder, the same code is supposed to update the existing `INKitRegister` record.

Instead, I receive this error:

> Error: Updating  'IN Kit' record raised at least one error. Please review the errors. Error: 'Total Cost' cannot be empty. Error: 'Ext. Cost' cannot be empty.

The Total Cost and Ext Cost are (presumably) automatically calculated when the record is inserted.

Q: **Why are the values not again calculated on Update?**  I wouldn't know where to begin to calculate them manually, and that doesn't really seem like a good idea anyway.

Comment: Is this related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63852541/single-field-value-wont-update-on-cache-update ?   Similarly, use *graph.Document.Insert(kit);* instead of setting Current to a new object and see if that clears up your trouble.

Comment: It is. It was prior to that question, and my new knowledge   Thank you.